# Google Maps Marker Cluster isn't working

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

For the life of me, I can not get this to work. I'm trying to pass the Marker Clusterers to my Google Map - but it's not working. I've got this map set up through Google Maps API and it's for a Wordpress website. The user can add locations using a Custom Post type. There are a lot of locations in close proximities, so I'm trying to use the MarkerCluster to lighten it up a bit. I've never used the MarkerCluster before, so it could be a small thing, too... not sure.
'var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map);' --This draws an error of: "Uncaught ReferenceError: MarkerClusterer is not defined"

Any insight? Any help is greatly appreciated!!

```
<?php // Index template
get_header(); ?>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>




<div class="twelve column">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="intro">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <hr>
            </div>

                <?php the_content(); ?>

                <header class="clearfix"></header>
                        <div id="mapcanvas"></div>
                                <?php
                                // For creating multiple, customized loops.
                                // http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
                                $custom_query = new WP_Query('post_type=locations'); // exclude category 9
                                while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
                                   <?php if(get_field('link')): ?>
                                      <div>
                                        <?php while(has_sub_field('link')): ?>
                                          <div>
                                              <p><?php the_sub_field('url'); ?></p>
                                          </div>
                                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                                      </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>

                                <?php
                                function get_single_term($post_id, $taxonomy)
                                {
                                  $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post_id, $taxonomy);
                                  if(!is_wp_error($terms)) {
                                    return '<a href="'.get_term_link($terms[0]->slug, $taxonomy).'">'.$terms[0]->name.'</a>';
                                  }
                                }

                                $i = 0;

                                // For creating multiple, customized loops.
                                // http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
                                    $custom_query = new WP_Query('post_type=location&posts_per_page=-1');
                                    while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();

                                      $title = get_the_title(); // Location title
                                      $map   = get_field('location'); // ACF location contains address and coordinates
                                      $terms = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'distributors', '', ' & ' )); // Get distributor terms and rm links
                                      $info  = '<strong>' . $title . '</strong><br>' . $map['address']; // Info window content
                                      $link = get_field('link');
                                      if($link){
                                        $info .= '<br><a href="http://'. $link .'">'. $link .'</a>';
                                      }
                                      $location[$i][0] = $title; // Store the post title
                                      $location[$i][1] = $map['coordinates']; // Store the ACF coordinates
                                      $location[$i][2] = json_encode($info); // Store info window content
                                      $location[$i][3] = strip_tags( get_single_term( $post->ID, 'distributors' )); // Get first term for marker icon

                                      $i ++;
                                    endwhile; ?>
                                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>

                                <script>
                                $(function initialize() {
                                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                                  // Center map on our main location
                                  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.583013,-93.63701500000002);
                                  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                                  // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling
                                  // Create an array of styles.
                                  var styles = [
                                    {
                                      stylers: [
                                        { saturation: -99.9 }
                                      ]
                                    }
                                  ];

                                  // Create a new StyledMapType object, passing it the array of styles,
                                  // as well as the name to be displayed on the map type control.
                                  var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {name: 'exile'});

                                  // Create a map object, and include the MapTypeId to add
                                  // to the map type control.
                                  var mapOptions = {
                                    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
                                    center: myLatLng,
                                    zoom: 14,
                                    disableDefaultUI: false,
                                    scrollwheel: true,
                                    draggable: true
                                  };

                                  // Display a map on the page
                                  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), mapOptions);
                                  var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map);
                                  map.setTilt(45);

                                  //Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
                                  map.mapTypes.set('exile', styledMap);
                                  map.setMapTypeId('exile');

                                // Marker icons
                                  typeObject = {
                                    "Others" : {
                                      "icon" : new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://exilebrewing.com/site/img/beer-mug.png', new google.maps.Size(18,26), new google.maps.Point(0,0), new google.maps.Point(9,26)),
                                      "shadow" : new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png', new google.maps.Size(40,34))
                                    }
                                  }

                                  // http://wrightshq.com/playground/placing-multiple-markers-on-a-google-map-using-api-3/
                                  // Multiple Markers
                                  var markers = [
                                    ["Exile Brewing Co", 41.583013,-93.63701500000002,"Others"],
                                    <?php
                                    if (count($location)>0) {
                                      foreach ($location as $key => $value){
                                        if ($key < (count($location)-1)){
                                          echo '["' . $location[$key][0] . '",' . $location[$key][1] . ',"' . $location[$key][3] . '"], ' . "\n";
                                        } else {
                                          echo '["' . $location[$key][0] . '",' . $location[$key][1] . ',"' . $location[$key][3] . '"]';
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                  ];
                                  var markers = [];
                                  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                                    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.photos[i].latitude,
                                        data.photos[i].longitude);
                                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({'position': latLng});
                                    markers.push(marker);
                                  }
                                  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);

                                  // Info Window Content
                                  var infoWindowContent = [
                                    ["<strong>Exile Brewing Co.</strong><br>1514 Walnut Street, Des Moines"],
                                    <?php
                                    if (count($location)>0) {
                                      foreach ($location as $key => $value){
                                        if ($key < (count($location)-1)) {
                                          echo '[' . $location[$key][2] . '], ' . "\n";
                                        } else {
                                          echo '[' . $location[$key][2] . ']';
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                  ];

                                  // Display multiple markers on a map
                                  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

                                  // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map
                                  for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
                                    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]); // ACF coordinates
                                    var icon = typeObject[markers[i][3]]['icon'];
                                    var shadow = typeObject[markers[i][3]]['shadow'];
                                    bounds.extend(position);
                                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                      position: position,
                                      map: map,
                                      title: markers[i][0],
                                      icon: icon,
                                      shadow: shadow
                                    });

                                    // Allow each marker to have an info window
                                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                                      return function() {
                                        infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                                      }
                                    })(marker, i));

                                    // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
                                    //map.fitBounds(bounds);
                                  }

                                  // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
                                  var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
                                    this.setZoom(15);
                                    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
                                  });

                                });
                                </script>

                                <div id="map-canvas"></div>


                <footer class="clearfix"></footer>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Also, here is the URL of the website for any other reference: http://exilebrewing.com/locations/

Comment: Dude , I am sorry, It might be only me , and it might be because I am tired or out of focus -. But I can not see where you have the `markerclusterer` script on your page . You have not included it

Comment: @ObmerkKronen I could definitely be missing something... I haven't used this before! Is there a specific script? I have it down after the comment that says //Display a map on the page with 'var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map);'

Comment: yes, but where is the  [script](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/)

Comment: @ObmerkKronen I feel dumb.. it's not in there. So I need to download a specific .js file for it? I guess I just thought since you don't need to download anything for a standard Google Map, that it was the same case with this!

Answer (score 1):

As per my comments :

You need to download the script ( [here](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/) ) and then Include it in your page.

Marker clusterer is not a `built-in` feature of google maps , but an `addon` script ..

```
  <script src="markerclusterer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or in the "correct" wordpress way :

```
wp_register_script( 'js_marker_clusterer', plugins_url( '/scripts/MarkerClusterer.js', __FILE__ ),'jquery' ); // or other dependencies descendents - preferably map JS or your custom.
wp_enqueue_script('js_marker_clusterer');
```

( change to your paths )

Also, look at the examples ( [HERE](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/examples/) ) and check their code ( and includes )

Comment: Thanks so much, I've got it linked up now. There is another error though with something not being found... I get an error with the rest of the code that says "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined" for this block of code from the Cluster documentation:

Comment: `var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.photos[i].latitude,
                                        data.photos[i].longitude);
                                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({'position': latLng});
                                    markers.push(marker);
                                  }
                                  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
`

Comment: Do I need to load in the cluster icon images?

Comment: Please look carefully at the examples . then make a SIMPLE map just to seethat you get all right with cluster . only then , after understanding , incorporate your wp query ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the third party [marker clusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/examples.html) script if you want to use it.

As specified in the documentation:

> Note: Be sure to include markerclusterer.js or markerclusterer_packed.js in your HTML document.

```
    <script src="/path/to/markerclusterer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```